# @angular/cli data from component to service

Tags: angular

I have a question regarding data and action flow in Angular.

I have a service A that fires of an API call and when the results return a options list is populated in Component A. On form submit, the value is captured and available in Component A. (So far so good and this is working fine.)

I now want to create a Service B that receives the form values and fires off a another API call to get the final data which should then be available to Component B.

My question is: How do I get the input data from Component A to Service B? I tried passing is along as a function value but since I am dealing with observables that doesn't seem to work.

Since there is quite a bit of code, I do not want to post here but it is available here: https://github.com/WebDevPDX/ng2-Meetup-Events.

Thank you for any help.